# Extract Data from pandas DF & recreate New DF

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, extract

I have pandas Df with two columns and almost 500 rows. Each columns have list of dictionaries with same keys.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnV0.png)]

I googled and search here for similar solution. but can't find it.
I need another Df same as below image. Here 1) sum of 5 Qty 2) avg of 5 Prices for col ABC and 3) sum of 5 Qty 4) avg of 5 Prices for col XYZ ( numbers not needed)

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HahzZ.png)]

#______________________________________________________________________

{'bestBids': {20: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '17875', 'price': '4.40'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '6300', 'price': '4.35'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '4925', 'price': '4.30'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '6700', 'price': '4.25'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '9175', 'price': '4.20'}], 22: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '1925', 'price': '5.70'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '25', 'price': '5.55'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '1200', 'price': '5.50'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '800', 'price': '5.45'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '800', 'price': '5.40'}], 24: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '325', 'price': '6.45'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '725', 'price': '6.40'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '25', 'price': '6.30'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '800', 'price': '6.20'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '25', 'price': '6.15'}], 34: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '1550', 'price': '7.00'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '75', 'price': '6.85'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '900', 'price': '6.80'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '1350', 'price': '6.65'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '500', 'price': '6.55'}], 44: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '50', 'price': '7.25'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '800', 'price': '7.20'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '250', 'price': '7.15'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '1800', 'price': '7.10'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '575', 'price': '7.05'}]}, 'bestAsks': {20: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '900', 'price': '4.50'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '1700', 'price': '4.55'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '250', 'price': '4.60'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '2425', 'price': '4.70'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '4425', 'price': '4.75'}], 22: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '3900', 'price': '5.80'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '400', 'price': '5.85'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '1025', 'price': '5.90'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '3000', 'price': '5.95'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '8300', 'price': '6.00'}], 24: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '625', 'price': '6.60'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '1150', 'price': '6.70'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '800', 'price': '7.00'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '1400', 'price': '7.90'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '50', 'price': '8.00'}], 34: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '1500', 'price': '7.40'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '1750', 'price': '7.45'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '50', 'price': '7.50'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '1000', 'price': '7.60'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '25', 'price': '7.70'}], 44: [{'number': '1', 'quantity': '125', 'price': '7.85'}, {'number': '2', 'quantity': '400', 'price': '9.00'}, {'number': '3', 'quantity': '400', 'price': '9.80'}, {'number': '4', 'quantity': '2000', 'price': '10.95'}, {'number': '5', 'quantity': '75', 'price': '11.00'}]}}

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you want to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you have to provide at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
pd.concat({c: df[c].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x)
                                      .agg({'quantity': 'sum', 'price': 'mean'})
                                      .rename({'quantity': 'Total Qty',
                                               'price': 'Avg Price'})
                         )
           for c in df}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Col ABC             Col XYZ          
  Total Qty Avg Price Total Qty Avg Price
0      10.0      20.0      85.0     170.0
1      35.0      70.0     110.0     220.0
2      60.0     120.0     135.0     270.0
```

Used input:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Col ABC                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Col XYZ
0             [{'number': 1, 'quantity': 0, 'price': 0}, {'number': 2, 'quantity': 1, 'price': 10}, {'number': 3, 'quantity': 2, 'price': 20}, {'number': 4, 'quantity': 3, 'price': 30}, {'number': 5, 'quantity': 4, 'price': 40}]  [{'number': 1, 'quantity': 15, 'price': 150}, {'number': 2, 'quantity': 16, 'price': 160}, {'number': 3, 'quantity': 17, 'price': 170}, {'number': 4, 'quantity': 18, 'price': 180}, {'number': 5, 'quantity': 19, 'price': 190}]
1            [{'number': 1, 'quantity': 5, 'price': 50}, {'number': 2, 'quantity': 6, 'price': 60}, {'number': 3, 'quantity': 7, 'price': 70}, {'number': 4, 'quantity': 8, 'price': 80}, {'number': 5, 'quantity': 9, 'price': 90}]  [{'number': 1, 'quantity': 20, 'price': 200}, {'number': 2, 'quantity': 21, 'price': 210}, {'number': 3, 'quantity': 22, 'price': 220}, {'number': 4, 'quantity': 23, 'price': 230}, {'number': 5, 'quantity': 24, 'price': 240}]
2  [{'number': 1, 'quantity': 10, 'price': 100}, {'number': 2, 'quantity': 11, 'price': 110}, {'number': 3, 'quantity': 12, 'price': 120}, {'number': 4, 'quantity': 13, 'price': 130}, {'number': 5, 'quantity': 14, 'price': 140}]  [{'number': 1, 'quantity': 25, 'price': 250}, {'number': 2, 'quantity': 26, 'price': 260}, {'number': 3, 'quantity': 27, 'price': 270}, {'number': 4, 'quantity': 28, 'price': 280}, {'number': 5, 'quantity': 29, 'price': 290}]
```

Comment: Trying to understand your code. Fumbling to figure out. got error msg"DataFrame constructor called with incompatible data and dtype: Could not convert 4.404.354.304.254.20 to numeric"   How can I send my actual DF

Comment: You can run `print(df.head().to_dict())` and update your question with the output